# mathematica physical constants without units

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, integration, constants, units-of-measurement

It is helpful to use physical constants included in mathematica. Unfortunately they all include units. This provides errors when trying to integrate numerically. Is there a way just to get the value of a variable without any dimensions?

Thank you!
Martin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If e.g. `c` is the speed of light:

```
c = UnitConvert[Quantity["SpeedOfLight"]]
```

Then the obvious way would be to write:

```
c/Quantity["Meters"/"Seconds"]
```

Because that way, you're certain the unitless quantity you work with actually means something in m/s, not e.g. ft/hour. In other words: If you wrote `c/Quantity["Feet"/"Hours"]`, the result would be the speed of light, in ft/hour, without a unit attached.

Alternatively, you could always write:

```
QuantityMagnitude[c]
```

Which just returns the magnitude, without the unit

Comment: you can also supply the desired unit to `UnitConvert`, ie `QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity["SpeedOfLight"],"Feet"/"Seconds"]`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help

```
In[1]:= sol = UnitConvert[Quantity["SpeedOfLight"]]

Out[1]= 299792458 m/s

In[2]:= FullForm[sol]

Out[2]//FullForm= Quantity[299792458,Times[Meters,Power[Seconds,-1]]]

In[3]:= mysol = First[sol]

Out[3]= 299792458

In[4]:= FullForm[mysol]

Out[4]//FullForm= 299792458
```